# Can't restore a db from scratch on an existing Django project

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I've got an existing Django 1.10 application and I want to create a new db locally from scratch.

Following these steps

```
$ createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U me -w my_db    # OK
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

I'm getting an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/customauth/admin.py", line 7, in <module>
    from core.admin import ShopInline
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/core/admin.py", line 242, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Campaign, CampaignAdmin)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 108, in register
    admin_obj = admin_class(model, self)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/core/admin.py", line 104, in __init__
    last_task = TaskState.objects.filter(name='core.tasks.compute_metrics', state='SUCCESS').order_by('tstamp').last()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 565, in last
    objects = list((self.reverse() if self.ordered else self.order_by('-pk'))[:1])
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/me/workspace/myproject-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "celery_monitor_taskstate" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ker_id", "celery_monitor_taskstate"."hidden" FROM "celery_mo...
```

Here is the relevant part of my `requirements.txt`

```
celery==4.0.2
django-celery-beat==1.0.1
django-celery-monitor==1.1.0
django-celery-results==1.0.1
```

And here is my in `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'modeltranslation',
    ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'django_countries',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'django_celery_monitor',
    ...
)
```

I tried to do a

```
$ ./manage.py migrate django_celery_monitor   # also tried for _results and _beat
```

but it throws the same error.

Comment: Show the full traceback. And why are you using `--fake` when you want to migrate for real?

Comment: You are right about the `--fake`, it doesn't make any sense. Anyway, the same problem occurs with or without the flag.

Comment: Oh I get it now... Had to read the entire traceback to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem came from a piece of my code in the admin module that was trying to retrieve a `TaskState` during initialisation. Hence the exception was raised even before any migration could be performed.